# Graph connectedness preserved by functors?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

In the context of the category of directed graphs with multi-edges:
Is there any functor that not preserve the connectedness of a graph?
Which other properties alike are preserved by default for functors?

I have for example the functor which removes directions from edges.
This one preserves connectedness, but I wonder if this functor in particular
does not preserve other common property.

Comment: Maybe there's a common understanding of this that I'm not aware of, but in your category of directed graphs allowing multi-edges, what are your morphisms?

Comment: To even talk about "preserving connectedness", you need the domain *and* codomain of the functor in question to be a category in which "connectedness" of objects makes sense. Maybe you want to restrict attention to functors $\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of directed graphs with multi-edges. But then you talk about "removing directions" from edges, which makes it sound like a functor $\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$, where $\mathcal{D}$ is the category of *undirected* graphs with multi-edges. In any case, you need to make the setting of your question clearer.

Comment: Also, remember that for any object $x$ in a category, you can define the constant functor $F_x$ with value $x$, which maps every object to $x$ and every morphism to $\text{id}_x$. If $x$ is a disconnected graph, $F_x$ will not preserve connectedness.

Comment: Just consider removing all edges. This gives an example of a functor that does not preserve connectness.